# Linkar autores ao final de cada post no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Como transformar o nome do autor em um link e ao clicar você consegue ver todos os posts desse autor no wordpress

Answer (score 0):

As funções [`the_author_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_posts_link/) e [`get_the_author_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_posts_link/) constroem o link completo, já com as tags HTML, por exemplo:

```
<p>Confira outros posts de <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
```